# Compilation Error Odeint CUDA Visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, boost, cuda, ode

I am using ODEint to solve set of coupled ode equations . I have a working code for CPU and am trying to implement the same on GPU using CUDA. I have compiled CUDA codes given in thrust libraries and those seem to work fine as well as the ones provided in the CUDA computing toolkit. However, while compiling the example CUDA code that comes with ODEint under thrust section I get the following error while compilation:

```
------ Build started: Project: try, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling with CUDA Build Rule...
1>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\\bin\nvcc.exe"    -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\"  --machine 32 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi   /MT  "  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\\include" -maxrregcount=0  --compile -o "Debug/lorenz_parameters.cu.obj" lorenz_parameters.cu 
1>lorenz_parameters.cu
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\boost/config/compiler/visualc.hpp(292) : warning C4005: 'BOOST_COMPILER' : macro redefinition
1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\boost/config/compiler/nvcc.hpp(11) : see previous definition of 'BOOST_COMPILER'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\boost/numeric/odeint/util/unit_helper.hpp(134): error: name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\boost/numeric/odeint/util/unit_helper.hpp(134): error: too many arguments for class template "boost::numeric::odeint::inverse_time"
1>2 errors detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/a0092778/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00002634_00000000-8_lorenz_parameters.compute_20.cpp1.ii".
1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Compiling with CUDA Build Rule..."
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\a0092778\Desktop\galib247\Projects\try\try\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>try - 3 error(s), 1 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I used boost libraries earlier also for my CPU code and those seem to be working fine. But when 
I tried incorporating boost libraries and converting my code to make it run on GPU, it showed the same error again.
I am using Visual Studio 2008 IDE for compilation.I am quite new to CUDA and would appreciate if someone could help me figure out the solution to the problem.

Comment: The CUDA toolchain can't compile boost headers. The only solution is to refactor your code so that no boost headers are put through an nvcc device code compilation trajectory. As long as they just get passed to the host compiler, there won't be problems.

Comment: I think this must be a problem of the Microsoft compiler. I can compile all examples with Linux and gcc (at least with gcc-4.4). We have similar problems on the issue list https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/issues/1 .